# TypeError: Object of type 'Playlist' is not JSON serializable

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful

**user model:**

```
class User(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    restaurant = db.Column(db.String(128))
    username = db.Column(db.String(128), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(128), unique=True)
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean(), default=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    admin = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False, nullable=False) 
    created_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=func.now())

    tracks = db.relationship("Track",
                    backref=db.backref('user'), 
                    uselist=True)
    playlists = db.relationship("Playlist",
                    backref=db.backref('user'), 
                    uselist=True)

    def __init__(self, restaurant, username, email, password):
        self.restaurant = restaurant
        self.username = username
        self.email = email
        self.password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(
            password, current_app.config.get('BCRYPT_LOG_ROUNDS')
        ).decode()


    def serialize(self):
       """Return object data in easily serializeable format"""
       return { 
        'id': self.id,
        'username': self.username,
        'email': self.email,
        'active': self.active,
        'admin': self.admin,
        'playlists' : self.playlists,
         }
```

**secondary:**

```
tracks = db.Table('tracks',
    db.Column('track_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('track.id')),
    db.Column('playlist_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('playlist.id')))
```

**playlist model:**

```
class Playlist(db.Model):
    """
    Model for storing playlist information belonging to a specific user
    """
    __tablename__ = 'playlist'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(50))
    artist = db.Column(db.String(50)) # we always need one for tagging purposes
    created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=func.now())

    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    menu_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('menu.id'))
    consumer_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('consumer.id'))

    tracks = db.relationship('Track', 
                        secondary=tracks,
                        backref=db.backref('playlists', 
                        lazy='dynamic'))

    def __init__(self, title, user):
        self.title = title
        self.user = user

    def serialize(self):
       """Return object data in easily serializeable format"""
       return {
           'id' : self.id,
           'created' : self.created,
           'title': self.title,
           'artist': self.artist,
           'tracks': [ item.serialize() for item in self.tracks]
       }
```

but when I'm trying to get data from database, like so:

```
from flask import Blueprint, jsonify, request, render_template
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

class UsersList(Resource):

  method_decorators = {'post': [authenticate_restful]}

  def get(self):
    """Get all users"""
    response_object = {
        'status': 'success',
        'data': {
            'users': [user.serialize() for user in User.query.all()]
        }
    }
    return response_object, 200

 api.add_resource(UsersList, '/users')
```

in spite of calling `serialize()`, I am getting the following error:

```
web_1| TypeError: Object of type 'Playlist' is not JSON serializable
```

Full traceback:

```
web_1      | 172.18.0.9 - - [30/Apr/2019 19:53:08] "GET /users HTTP/1.0" 500 -
web_1      | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1      |   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2309, in __call__
web_1      |     return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
web_1      |   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
web_1      |     response = self.handle_exception(e)
web_1      |   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 269, in error_router
web_1      |     return original_handler(e)
web_1      |   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 161, in wrapped_function
web_1      |     return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
web_1      |   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
web_1      |     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
web_1      |   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 34, in reraise
web_1      |     raise value.with_traceback(tb)
web_1      |   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
web_1      |     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
web_1      |   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
web_1      |     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
web_1      |   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 269, in error_router
web_1      |     return original_handler(e)
web_1      |   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 161, in wrapped_function
web_1      |     return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
web_1      |   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
web_1      |     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
web_1      |   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 34, in reraise
web_1      |     raise value.with_traceback(tb)
web_1      |   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
web_1      |     rv = self.dispatch_request()
web_1      |   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_debugtoolbar/__init__.py", line 125, in dispatch_request
web_1      |     return view_func(**req.view_args)
web_1      |   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 462, in wrapper
web_1      |     return self.make_response(data, code, headers=headers)
web_1      |   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 491, in make_response
web_1      |     resp = self.representations[mediatype](data, *args, **kwargs)
web_1      |   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_restful/representations/json.py", line 21, in output_json
web_1      |     dumped = dumps(data, **settings) + "\n"
web_1      |   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
web_1      |     **kw).encode(obj)
web_1      |   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 201, in encode
web_1      |     chunks = list(chunks)
web_1      |   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 430, in _iterencode
web_1      |     yield from _iterencode_dict(o, _current_indent_level)
web_1      |   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 404, in _iterencode_dict
web_1      |     yield from chunks
web_1      |   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 404, in _iterencode_dict
web_1      |     yield from chunks
web_1      |   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 325, in _iterencode_list
web_1      |     yield from chunks
web_1      |   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 404, in _iterencode_dict
web_1      |     yield from chunks
web_1      |   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 325, in _iterencode_list
web_1      |     yield from chunks
web_1      |   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 437, in _iterencode
web_1      |     o = _default(o)
web_1      |   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 180, in default
web_1      |     o.__class__.__name__)
web_1      | TypeError: Object of type 'Playlist' is not JSON serializable
```

what am I missing?